# useContext with a connect button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I am trying to make a connect button when the user clicks on it and connect he store the value inside a global state that i can use inside the whole application but this code doesn't work at all , why is it wrong ?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const UserContexts = React.createContext();

const UserContext =  ({children}) => {
  
  const [getUser, setGetUser] = useState(null);

  function connect() {
    ethereum.request({ method : 'eth_requestAccounts'}).then(accounts => {
       const account = accounts[0];
       setGetUser(account)
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getUser ? null : connect();
  },[])
  
  const { Provider } = UserContexts;

  return (
     getUser ? <Provider value={getUser} >
      {children}
    </Provider>: null
  )
}

export default UserContext

// navbar 

import UserContext from './userContext'

<button onClick={UserContext.connect()} > connect </button>
```

when a user clicks on navbar connect button he login then when he login the _app saves the state globally so I can use it everywhere inside the app , I know this is a wrong syntax but how can I make it work ?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem combined `useContext` and `useReducer`.

```
import React, {createContext,useContext,useEffect,useReducer} from "react";
const UserContext = createContext();

export function useBlockchainContext() {
    return useContext(BlockchainContext);
}
function reducer(state, { type, payload }) {
    return {
        ...state,
        [type]: payload,
    };
};
const init_state = {
    user: ""
}
export default function Provider({ children }) {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, init_state);
    return (
        <BlockchainContext.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
            {children}
        </BlockchainContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

*// navbar*

```
import { useBlockchainContext } from "../userContext";

export default function NavBar() {
    const [state,dispatch] = useBlockchainContext();
    const connect = ()=> {
        ethereum.request({ method : 'eth_requestAccounts'}).then(accounts => {
           const account = accounts[0];
           dispatch({
              type: "user",
              payload: {
                 account
              }
           });
        })
    };

    return(
        <button onClick={()=>connect()} >{state.user !==""?state.user.slice(0, 4) + "..." + state.user.slice(-4):connect}</button>
    )
}
```

Comment: this looks cool but its not working it always says that
 const [state,dispatch] = BlockchainContexts(); 

ran with error of TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))